# Error Analytics API Cannot retrieve test results

Tags: prestashop, analytics

im trying some days configure the analytics to my new website, but when i put the codes, they are ok, but i have this error message:

"Cannot retrieve test results"

You know what i do wrong? I have other website, and works well...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXV5G.png)